# Creating TermDocumentMatrix in Python 2.7 with textmining package (attribute error)

Tags: python-2.7, text-processing

Im trying to make a `TermDocumentMatrix` in Python using the *textmining* package. The following code causes an error:

**CODE:**

```
import textmining
tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()
```

**ERROR:**

```
File "<ipython-input-7-50b739ce2532>", line 1, in <module>
    tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TermDocumentMatrix'
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with `Python v2.7`.

Unfortunately it has to do with an older version this package has been made.

We shouldn't have this problem with `Python v2.5` or lower.

I've read somewhere that there must be a way to convert this 'old' package, so it's compatible with the newer versions of `Python`.

I'll keep you posted when I know more about this compatibility error.

Comment: Ok thank you! I've worked around the problem now. So no further help is needed. Also, it seems that I have created some conflicting namespace issues by naming my script 'textmining'.